# Silverlight to self hosted WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a silverlight application which has a WCF in it.
Since it is a self hosted WCF I've understand I have to add an interface something like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPolicyRetriever
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/clientaccesspolicy.xml")]
    Stream GetSilverlightPolicy();
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/crossdomain.xml")]
    Stream GetFlashPolicy();
}
```

and the implemetation:

```
Stream StringToStream(string result)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    }
    public Stream GetSilverlightPolicy()
    {
        string result = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <access-policy>
            <cross-domain-access>
                <policy>
                    <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
                        <domain uri=""*""/>
                    </allow-from>
                    <grant-to>
                        <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
                    </grant-to>
                </policy>
            </cross-domain-access>
        </access-policy>";
        return StringToStream(result);
    }
    public Stream GetFlashPolicy()
    {
        string result = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM ""http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"">
        <cross-domain-policy>
            <allow-access-from domain=""*"" />
        </cross-domain-policy>";
        return StringToStream(result);
    }
```

but I don't understand the next steps I have to do in order the silverlight calls to WCF will not raise communcation exception.

Can you please show me the code I have to write and where?
(when I google it I didn't understand when the WCF calls to retrive the clientaccesspolicy, and what is the endpoint I have to add, I'm new to silverlight and WCF and don't know exaclty why I have to add an endpoint...)

this is my ServiceReference.ClientConfig:

```
    <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMapService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4693/MapService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMapService" contract="MapService.IMapService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMapService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

thank you!

Comment: Can you give me an example url where your service runs?  (ie http://myapp.com/service.svc)? I can better get ya an answer with that.  Feel free to abstract whatever ya need, just an example from which you can derive your solution

Comment: @Taylor: here is an example:http://localhost:4693/MapService.svc

Comment: And when you go to http://localhost:4693/clientaccesspolicy.xml what do you get?

Comment: ok, so thats what we gotta solve.  How about http://localhost:4693/MapService.svc/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Silverlight Http stack (HTTP clientaccesspolicy.xml)**

Must be hosted in root of your target domain. Could be easily checked with web browser.
Silverlight checks it automatically one time.

**Silverlight 3 sockets (Custom policy server)**

I've already made this policy server for Silverlight for Log2Console app.

I think this code may help [SL Policy Server](http://log2console.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69040#1419107).

It has to be hosted on special port TCP port 943.

**Silverligt 4 sockets (by default as in SL3, but can be opted-in for HTTP)**

Set the SocketAsyncEventArgs.SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol property on the SocketAsyncEventArgs passed to Socket.ConnectAsync to SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol.Http.

**Silverlight possible ports range**

80, 443, 4502-4532 (if allowed in clientaccesspolicy.xml)

[Detailed documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: You just need to host my policy server on your in server side. Silverlight calls policy server automatically. And policy server is not a HTTP server like you'd like it to be with WCF.

Comment: Probably your port is our of allowed range